# Passing Vec3 Array to Vertex Shader with ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, shader, vertex-shader

How do I pass an array of vec3 data to a vertex shader using ThreeJS?

```
air_parcel_pos: {
   type: "???",
   value: the array of data
}
```

Comment: `.type` is not used. three.js r.103.

Comment: I was wondering why this page in the documentation ( https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Uniform ) didn't make sense to me.  Thanks.

Comment: dupe' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25249190/passing-an-array-of-vec2-to-shader-in-three-js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initialization value has to be an array of values which correspond to the GLSL data type.

e.g.

If the uniform variable is an array of `vec3`

```c
uniform vec3 u_array[3];
```

then the initialization value can be an array of [`THREE.Vector3`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3)

```js
var uniforms = {
    u_array: {value: [
        new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0),
        new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0),
        new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1)
    ] }
};

var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({  
    uniforms: uniforms,
    vertexShader: // ...
    fragmentShader: // ...
});
```

Further data types are [`Vector2`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector2), [`Vector4`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector4) or [`Color`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Color). An array of `float` or `int` can be set by an array of values.

Comment: Thanks, your answer expanded my understanding this.